# android HTTP post multipart

Tags: android, html, http-post, multipart

Hello, I have a website part described as below:

```
<div id="insertA">
    <form class="MultiFile-intercepted" enctype="multipart/form-data"
        method="post" onsubmit="return checkAnomalyFields();"
        action="dodajN.html">
        <table style="border-weight: 0px">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="wybory"><select id="typ" onchange="typeSelected()" size="1"
                        name="typuId">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Szerokość: <input id="szer" type="text" onchange="setMarker()"
                        value="" name="szer">
                        <div id="szerErr" class="err">Proszę podać szerokość na terenie
                            Polski (49-55).</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>Długość: <input id="dlug" type="text" onchange="setMarker()"
                        value="" name="dlug">
                        <div id="dlugErr" class="err">Proszę podać długość na terenie
                            Polski (14-25).</div> <input id="id" type="hidden" value=""
                        name="id">
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

I want to make a HTTP POST request to send data from my client and put it into forms.
I am doing this as follows:

```
try {
    HttpClient client = new MyHttpClient(Send.this);  
    String postURL = "url";
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL); 
    //FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);  
    //reqEntity.addPart("myFile", bin);
    reqEntity.addPart("typuId", new StringBody("1"));
    reqEntity.addPart("statusuId", new StringBody("2"));
    reqEntity.addPart("szer", new StringBody("52.321911"));
    reqEntity.addPart("dlug", new StringBody("19.464111000000003"));
    reqEntity.addPart("opis",  new StringBody("jakis opis"));

    post.setEntity(reqEntity);  
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);  
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();  
    AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(Send.this);
    alert.setTitle("Niepoprawne dane").setMessage(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity)).setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();

    if (resEntity != null) {    
        Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is when I read the response I get the HTML code of the site that I am requesting without a success code or anything similar. It looks like I am requesting for site content, but not submitting the form. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: i don't see that's a problem. you are calling a website, not a webservice. the result of the post is supposed to be a user friendly html page, not a cryptic response code. you _may_ try to understand what the html returned is.

Comment: njzk2 so you say that server do not process my request properly?

Comment: no. I'm saying that you are not processing the server answer properly. it is an html page that it is supposed to return, and it is up to you to check if that seems right.

Comment: the problem is that it looks like im am not posting ( hitting the submit buton) but only ask for content of page.. i just can't get it why

Comment: your are posting. try to get the content of the result, save it in an html file and view it.

Comment: i get exacly the same form i was submitting into with no data i put in MultipartEntity

Comment: i assume you are posting to dodajN.html

Comment: actually there is no difference between posting to dodajN.html or to new in both cases i get same response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're submitting to a `.html` file. Generally servers aren't configured to treat those files as scripts, which means the data you're submitting is simply ignored and dumped. To handle a form submission, you have to submit to a script or other program specifically designed to handle that submission, e.g. a php script.

Comment: actually this is some kind of blog an i want to be able to make another entry on client. i am requesting a site which looks like blog.jsp?action=new

Comment: then what's `action="dodajN.html"` all about, then?

Comment: after test there is no difference in my case if i use url=someurl/blogjsp?action=new or url=someurl/blogjsp?action="dodajN.html" i a little bit confused right now

Answer (score 0):

OK, to clarify what Marc B said: `action="dodajN.html"` is almost certainly wrong. I've never seen a web server that lets you do this (of course, anything is possible).  It should probably be `action="cgi-bin/something"` or something like that.

It's actually not that important however, since your app isn't using the `action` clause anyway, but rather writing to "url" which is even more wrong.  If you would tell us exactly what url you're really writing to, it might help.

But ultimately, the way you debug this is to look at the server logs and see what's happening at that end.

As a general rule, when I'm developing something like this, I first write the server-side cgi script and a web page to use it.  Once my API is working through the web page, only then do I start trying to call the cgi script from an Android app.

My debugging process consists of:  1) Reading the server logs.  2) Having my cgi scripts write their own debug logs.  3) Having my android app dump the response code and headers to logcat.