# HTTPPost with multiple params in body

Tags: android, http-post

I'm kinnda newbie at android, so i need your help, guys.
I'm developing an android application which needs a connection to an api.

First time the user logs in, using `api/login` url. The post method needs to have `X-Requested-With : XMLHttpRequest` header, and two elements in the body : `email` & `password`.
The response is a token JWT which i need to store it. How can i do that?

What i made so far :

```
private String url;
private DefaultHttpClient httpClient;


public void requestLogin(String username, String password) {
    makeNewURL("login");
    try {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        post.addHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

    } catch (Exception x) {

    }
}


public void makeNewURL(String page) {
    try {
        url = ("api/" + page);
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    } catch (Exception x) {

    }

}
```

How can i set email and password `key` &`value`as Postman has?

I searched a lot about this question, but i didn't find anything with DefaultHttpClient.
Thanks !

Comment: checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032736/android-http-post-multipart

Answer (score 0):

Try with [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). Here you can handle all HTTP client related code from Android and Java to consume the API.